# Domain root path workaround

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

I'm crafting a Laravel application for a client of mine but he took a webhosting which does not allow me to point a domain to a certain folder. The root folder is always the folder named after the domain. I still need the domain root to be the *public* folder of my application.

example:

> Domain.com root path is *sites/domain.com/*, but I need it to be in *sites/domain.com/public/* - only the webhosting does not allow this kind of configuration

Is there a way to work around this? Like, with HTAccess or some PHP trick?

Comment: Could probably do this with .htaccess via something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]` ? You can also do this with PHP tricks like an `index.php` in your root that has a `header("Location: /public/index.php")` or something like that.

Comment: Your last option is not sufficient since laravel expects public to be the root folder.